# How to continue recognition in the Web Speech API without repeating the permissions info bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

I'm a bit perplexed by the [Web Speech API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API): namely, I've not figured out how to incrementally handle recognition.

Suppose I have three inputs:

```
<input id=a>
<input id=b>
<input id=c>
```

And I'd like to recognize three input words, shifting focus to the next input after each recognition. Is this possible using the API as it exists? The tutorials I've seen (such as [this one](http://www.sitepoint.com/experimenting-web-speech-api/) seem to require repeated clicking on the permissions bar, which is super annoying.

Is there any way to set access to the microphone per-page-load or something like that?

Comment: I believe the **continuous** property does that

`a = new webkitSpeechRecognition()`
`a.continuous = true`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the case, industrialpoet's answer below turns out to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to avoid the repeated "permission click" for a new recognition is to serve your page via https and have a valid certificate installed for your domain. This is a change that Google introduced in the last year.

Comment: Thanks, this is right, I saw that there is a comment in the article linked above to that effect. I seem to have managed to make it work on my local machine even without a valid certificate, but that's fine for development.

Thanks!